# word for one who thinks in many ways than others

Tags: synonyms

words for one who thinks in different and unique ways than others think and has many solutions to a problem . when a person thinks the same problem in many ways and solve the problem in their mind many times and always be one step ahead of others , what is he called.

Comment: You're asking for too many things at once. Do you want a word for somebody who solves problems faster than other people, who thinks differently than other people, or who comes up with multiple solutions simultaneaously? They may be related, but not necessarily. Please clarify. Also, provide at least one sample sentence with a space in which such a word can be put.

Comment: who comes up with multiple solutions simultaneously plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**mastermind**

> (from [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mastermind))
>
> A person with an extraordinary intellect or skill that is markedly superior to his or her peers.

See also [**Batman Gambit**](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BatmanGambit) or [**Xanatos Gambit**](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/XanatosGambit) on TV Tropes.  A [**chessmaster**](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheChessmaster) can think three moves ahead of their opponent.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a ***genius***:

> [Oxford English Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/genius):
>
>   1. Exceptional intellectual or creative power or other natural ability.
>
>      A person who is exceptionally intelligent or creative,
>        either generally or in some particular respect.
>
> [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=genius):
>
>   - A person of extraordinary intellect and talent.
>
>     A person who has an exceptionally high intelligence quotient,
>       typically above 140.
>
> [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/genius_1):
>
>   someone who is much more intelligent or skillful than other people
>   *Bach’s Magnificat is clearly the work of a genius.*
>   *She was a mathematical genius.*